# Using PIL to analyze a video frame by frame

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm working on using PIL to average the pixel intensities over a subarea of a video.  What I want to do is:

-Use ffmpeg to turn the video into several frames
-Use PIL to choose a window in each frame (this is the step I'd like help with)
-Do some sort of analysis on that window in each frame, and aggregate the data (like, say, average color vs. time)

I'm at quite a loss as to how to do the middle step -- does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: You might want to explain what you mean by a window, a rectangle?

Comment: I apologize for vagueness -- a rectangle or circle is the simplest shape I can think of, though any shape would probably do.  I'd just like a way to keep track of a group of pixels through several images.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Do you want a _fixed_ rectangle (e.g. the top left quadrant) from each frame, or do you want some algorithm to track a group of pixels (e.g. following a moving person)? The latter is __much__ harder.

Comment: I want them to follow a <b>fixed</b> space in a set of images (the former).  I'd like the ability to have that subset of pixels be variable and draw a new rectangle/circle/shape around the pixels I care about for each set of frames.

Comment: It seems like I may want some sort of GUI -- like pygame, wxpython, etc. to handle the mouse components.  I haven't used anything for visualizing Python beyond matplotlib; anyone have suggestions for a python gui to learn?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using Tkinter:

```py
import Tkinter
import Image, ImageDraw, ImageTk

window = Tkinter.Tk()
window.title('Calcium Imaging Software')

mouse_X = 0
mouse_Y = 0
ellipseBox = []
listOfCircles = []

#stuff to set up the image
image = Image.open("test.jpg")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(window, width=image.size[0], height=image.size[1])
canvas.pack()
image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
canvas.create_image(image.size[0]//2, image.size[1]//2, image=image_tk)

#define a function to be run on the mouseclick
def drawEllipse(event):
    global ellipseBox
    print "clicked at: ", event.x, event.y
    mouse_X = event.x
    mouse_Y = event.y
    ellipseBox.append((mouse_X,mouse_Y))
    print "box corners: ",ellipseBox
    #When two corners are selected, draw the ellipse
    if len(ellipseBox) == 2:
        draw.ellipse(ellipseBox,outline=(255,255,255))
        listOfCircles.append(tuple(ellipseBox))
        ellipseBox = []
        window.update()
#bind mouse click to drawing an ellipse
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", drawEllipse)
Tkinter.mainloop()
```

And this does almost everything I want!  However, I can't get the ellipses to show up on the image -- any suggestions?